# Python requests-HTML library doesn't work sometimes

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

### Definition

I am scraping from a website using the requests_html library. The `get_product_info(url: str) -> dict` method I wrote returns the product names, prices and the url of the product on the page.

### Problem

I noticed that when I run the function several times with the same url, it doesn't always return a result.

##### Example

[image]

What exactly is the problem?

### Code

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

sub_cat2_link = 'https://www.sokmarket.com.tr/bulasik-c-1442'


def get_product_info(url: str) -> dict:
    r2 = session.get(url)
    r2.html.render()
    product_names = [item.text for item in r2.html.find('main.listing-results strong')]
    product_prices = [item.text for item in r2.html.find('main.listing-results div.pricetag')]
    product_links = [MAIN_URL + item.links.pop() for item in r2.html.find('main.listing-results a.productbox-wrap')]
    return {"prod": product_names, "price": product_prices, "prod_link": product_links}


result = get_product_info(sub_cat2_link)
print(result)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the requests_html module. However, if it's anything like the ubiquitous requests module then it's possible that your call to get() is returning with an HTML status code that is not 200. This could be something like a 503 or maybe 429 if there's rate-limiting on the site you're trying to access

Comment: I checked it. Status code 200 but no data. I used sleep method between lines of code but nothing changed.

Comment: You will obviously need to change your code but my only suggestion is to use the 'requests' module. I may be missing something but I can't see how/why HTTP status 200 would be returned with no content

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I ended up retrying the render and so far it is working for me.

```
for attempt in range(3):
    try:
        r2.html.render()
        #do something
    except:
        time.sleep(5) # not sure if this is needed
        print(attempt)
    else: 
        break
else:
     print('all attempts failed')
```